# Removing the block "Popular Tags" from the index view in Magento

Tags: magento, layout

I started working with Magento this week and I'm trying to create a new theme. Following the ["Designing for Magento"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how-to/designing/designing-for-magento) article of the wiki, I tried to remove the Popular Tags block from the index view, adding this line to local.xml on magento\app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\layout:

```
<remove name="tags_popular"/>
```

I don't why, but the tags are still there while if I do the following the language switcher disappears:

```
<remove name="store_language"/>
```

I also tried this to no effect:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>tags_popular</name></action>
</reference>
```

I even deleted tag.xml and the tags are still there!

I know that I can get rid of them disabling the Mage_tag in the backend, buy I want to understand why this is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try disabling the cache. If the cache is on (which is the default option), you might not see the changes you make to the templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How silly, the popular tags were shown in the main page because they came in the default code of the content page (menu: CMS > Pages), so I just had to erase that :P

Answer (score 5):

Just add this in your **theme->page.xml** default block

```
<remove name="tags_popular"/>
```

you can remove block any of magneto. then you can remove after it's block name.
here you see tag_popular it's block name remove plus it's block name 
 [Remove default magento block](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/05/remove-default-magneto-block-like-news.html)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look into tag.xml where you will find this code, which you have to comment out:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Tag -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtm">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>tag/popular.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```